# Obtaining coordinates of convexhull polygons using DBSCAN and CONVEXHULL

Tags: python, convex-hull

I am using DBSCAN to cluster coordinates together and then using convexhull to draw 'polygons' around each cluster. I then want to extract the coordinates of the convex hull objects.  However, the code im using (hull.simplices) does not match the coordinate system I am using.

Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull



Lat=[10,10,20,23,27,28,29,34,11,34,66,22]
Lon=[39,40,23,21,11,29,66,33,55,22,11,55]

D=list(zip(Lat, Lon))
df = pd.DataFrame(D,columns=['LAT','LON'])

X=np.array(df[['LAT', 'LON']])


kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
epsilon = 1500 / kms_per_radian
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=3) 


model=db.fit(np.radians(X))
cluster_labels = db.labels_




num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))



cluster_labels = cluster_labels.astype(float)
cluster_labels[cluster_labels == -1] = np.nan



labels = pd.DataFrame(db.labels_,columns=['CLUSTER_LABEL'])

dfnew=pd.concat([df,labels],axis=1,sort=False)





z=[] #HULL simplices coordinates will be appended here

for i in range (0,num_clusters-1):
    dfq=dfnew[dfnew['CLUSTER_LABEL']==i]
    Y = np.array(dfq[['LAT', 'LON']])
    hull = ConvexHull(Y)
    plt.plot(Y[:, 1],Y[:, 0],  'o')
    z.append(hull.simplices)
    for simplex in hull.simplices:
        ploted=plt.plot( Y[simplex, 1], Y[simplex, 0],'k-',c='m')


plt.show()

print(z)
```

Can you advise the code required to get list of coordinates for each convexhull object(to be same as original coordinates ass see in the plot)?

This is output iam getting:

[array([[2, 0],
[5, 4],
[5, 2],
[3, 0],
[3, 4]], dtype=int32), array([[0, 1],
[2, 1],
[2, 0]], dtype=int32)]

As can be seen, it does not match the coordinates I used.

Comment: Hi, i have appended the code and removed the picture table. I have checked whether to use geopandas however the coordinates are not arranged in sequence to be able to construct polygon objects using geopandas hence i used convex hull which seems more straightfoward. any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure `kms_per_radian = 6371.0088` is correct for all lat longs. I Think you need to use some projected coordinate system, perform clusterdbscan then convert back to lat long.

Comment: you are right. For the purpose of the dataset iam working with (not in the example above), most of the datapoints are near the equator hence its sufficient approximation for the precision required. Nevertheless, its something ill be looking to correct later on. Regarding the main question, any suggestions?

Comment: it seems that  z.append(hull.points) does the trick

Comment: @TheOracle: hull.points returns all input point. To only get the points of the convex hull as a list of points try to replace `z.append(hull.simplices)` with `z.append(Y[hull.vertices,:].tolist())`

Comment: Regarding km/ radians=6371. Ive thought about it and i think it 'may' not matter depending on how DBSCAN does the calculation. So assuming earth is near perfect sphere, at any point along its surface the actual circumference is constant (2*pi*6371km). However its only when you break it down into 2D  (Latitude or Longitude) or you take crossections at different Latitudes or Longitudes then the circumference of the circle(not the 'sphere' iff that makes sense), changes.   Is anybody aware about how DBSCAN does the actual computation (the detail algorithm) and hence advise if 6371 need correction